# Show array in a ComboBox (C#) from query SQL

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, combobox, windows-mobile

I'm trying to show all rows of the table (e.g. Colours of the 'colour' column) in a ComboBox (on C# for WindowsMobile) but i don't know how fill a array with fields of the table.
I have a database and table 'tableColours'.

```
... //load database... OK
SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(conSTR);
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT colour FROM tableColours", connection);
connection.Open();
```

Now I need fill one object or array with all colours of the table... Any idea?...

Finally I will show this colours in a ComboBox with a forward code (but this string[] colours must to fill with sentence SQL of the table):

```
string[] colours = new string[] {"Red", "White", "Black", "Blue"}; //provisional

foreach (string col in colours)
{
    comboBoxEESS.Items.Add(col);
}
connection.Close();
```

Sorry for my English. Thanks!!!

Comment: what do you want to do?? Not getting your question clearly...

Comment: I want to save "colors" that I read of table (query SELECT sql) in an array. Then this array, I show in a ComboBox.

Comment: There is no need of array directly use SqlReader to read value and put that into combo box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(conSTR);
                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT colour FROM tableColours", connection);
                connection.Open();
                DataTable colours = new DataTable();
                colours.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                DataRow dr = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < Colors.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    dr = colours.Rows[i];
                    comboBoxEESS.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());

                }
                connection.Close();
```

I use DataTable instead Array.